# Schema for Silverlight clientaccesspolicy.xml file

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain

Can someone tell me where I can find the **schema** for the **clientaccesspolicy.xml** file that Silverlight need for cross domain service calls?

Answer (score 1):

I took me some time in Google to find this (which is why I decided to post this Q/A), but here is a link to msdn where the format is described (although an actual schema file is not provided):

[Link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx)

To see the format description, scroll down to the section called **Silverlight Policy File Format**.